# How to scrape link from div element with ng-if attribute using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Div element looks like this

`<a ng-if="!People.disableActions" class="Name" ng-click="!People.disableActions && People.searchByAddress($event, People.record.address, People.record.Title)" href="https://...">Anna Bros</a> ==$0`

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
linne = '''<a ng-if="!People.disableActions" 
               class="Name" ng-click="!People.disableActions && 
               People.searchByAddress($event, People.record.address, People.record.Title)" 
                href="https://...">Anna Bros</a> ==$0'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(linne, 'lxml')
ng_if_Att =  [values["ng-if"] for values in soup.findAll("a")]
href_link =  [values["href"] for values in soup.findAll("a")]

print "ng_if attr = {0}".format(ng_if_Att[0])
print "href_link attr = {0}".format(href_link[0])
```

---

```
#output:
ng_if attr = !People.disableActions
href_link attr = https://...
```